# Why do we need to Treat() MDSYS.ST_GEOMETRY as ST_LINESTRING to use ST_PointN(1)?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle18c, oracle-spatial

*MDSYS.ST_GEOMETRY; Oracle 18c:*

---

The following query works. It extracts the first point from an MDSYS.ST_GEOMETRY:

```
--Source: https://www.spdba.com.au/using-oracles-st_geometry-type-hierarchy-with-sdo_geometry-st_pointn-and-st_numpoints/

with    cte as (
select  treat(mdsys.st_geometry.from_wkt('LINESTRING(10 10, 20 20)',26917) as mdsys.st_linestring) as shape
from    dual
)
select 
    (shape).st_pointn(1) as first_point
from 
    cte

Result:
MDSYS.ST_POINT(MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 26917, MDSYS.SDO_POINT_TYPE(10, 10, NULL), NULL, NULL))
```

---

I don't understand why we need to `Treat()` the ST_GEOMETRY supertype as an ST_LINESTRING subtype in order to use `ST_PointN()` to get the point.

For example, if I remove the `Treat(... as ST_LINESTRING)`, then I get an error:

```
with    cte as (
select  mdsys.st_geometry.from_wkt('LINESTRING(10 10, 20 20)',26917) as shape
from    dual
)
select 
    (shape).st_pointn(1) as first_point
from 
    cte

Error:
ORA-00904: "MDSYS"."ST_GEOMETRY"."ST_POINTN": invalid identifier
```

Why do I get that error when I remove `Treat()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why do I get that error when I remove `Treat()`?

- `ST_LINESTRING` is a sub-type of `ST_CURVE` which, in turn, is a sub-type of `ST_GEOMETRY`.
- `ST_POINTN` is a member function declared on the sub-type `ST_CURVE` and `ST_LINESTRING` inherits this function.
- `ST_POINTN` is not declared as a member function on the parent type `ST_GEOMETRY`.
- The `ST_GEOMETRY.FROM_WKT()` function returns an `ST_GEOMETRY` instance that, in this case is a actually a `ST_LINESTRING` sub-type but the return type of the function is `ST_GEOMETRY` as it could return any child sub-type.

When you remove `TREAT()` then you are trying to call the `ST_POINTN` member function on the parent type `ST_GEOMETRY` and, as the error message states `"MDSYS"."ST_GEOMETRY"."ST_POINTN"` is an invalid identifier because the type does not have that member function.

When you include `TREAT()` then you cast the super-type to the sub-type and then call the member function on that sub-type and the member function does exist so it works.

---

A similar example is:

```sql
CREATE TYPE parent_type IS OBJECT (
 x NUMBER,
 y NUMBER
) NOT FINAL;

CREATE TYPE child_type UNDER parent_type (
  MEMBER FUNCTION get_x RETURN NUMBER
);

CREATE TYPE BODY child_type IS
  MEMBER FUNCTION get_x RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN self.x;
  END;
END;
/
```

Then:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION create_parent RETURN PARENT_TYPE
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN child_type(1, 2);
END;
/
```

If you use:

```sql
SELECT create_parent().get_x() FROM DUAL;
```

Then the function declares it returns a `PARENT_TYPE` and so the member function is called on that type, even though the actual returned value is a `CHILD_TYPE`, so raises the error:

> ```
> ORA-00904: "SCHEMA_NAME"."PARENT_TYPE"."GET_X": invalid identifier
> ```

If you use `TREAT` to cast the returned parent to its actual child type:

```sql
SELECT TREAT(create_parent() AS child_type).get_x() FROM DUAL;
```

Then the output is:

> | TREAT(CREATE_PARENT()ASCHILD_TYPE).GET_X() |
> | --- |
> | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=48d75cded63f5a89d3cb4d25ecb89e26)*