# Why does (SHAPE).SDO_ORDINATES(1) syntax fail, but (SHAPE).ST_PointN(1) succeeds?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle18c, oracle-spatial

*Oracle 18c:*

---

In a related question, we determined:

> The syntax of extracting collection elements by index is not supported
> in SQL.

So a query that uses this syntax will fail: `(shape).sdo_ordinates(1)`,

```
select
  (shape).sdo_ordinates(1) as startpoint_x
from
  (select sdo_geometry('linestring(1 2, 3 4, 5 6)') as shape 
   from dual)

Error:
ORA-00904: "MDSYS"."SDO_GEOMETRY"."SDO_ORDINATES": invalid identifier
```

Source: [Why does SHAPE.SDO_ORDINATES(1) work in PL/SQL, but not in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72570611/why-does-shape-sdo-ordinates1-work-in-pl-sql-but-not-in-sql)

---

However, I have a query that is similar (different datatype) that succeeds when I use seemingly similar syntax: `(shape).st_pointn(1)`.

```
select
  (shape).st_pointn(1) as startpoint
from
  (select treat(st_geometry.from_wkt('Linestring(1 2, 3 4, 5 6)',26917) as st_linestring) as shape
   from dual)

Result:
MDSYS.ST_POINT(MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 26917, MDSYS.SDO_POINT_TYPE(1, 2, NULL), NULL, NULL))
```

Source: [Why do we need to Treat() MDSYS.ST_GEOMETRY as ST_LINESTRING to use ST_PointN(1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72666969/why-do-we-need-to-treat-mdsys-st-geometry-as-st-linestring-to-use-st-pointn1)

---

Why does `(SHAPE).SDO_ORDINATES(1)` fail, but `(SHAPE).ST_PointN(1)` succeeds?

Comment: Because [`St_PointN`](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/st-pointn.htm) is a function that accepts a point index and returns the point with that index. This syntax is not a collection element access.

Comment: See [db_fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8794555222162bac8c9d5369fded9589)

Comment: @astentx That `St_PointN` link you shared points to a different datatype...a proprietary implementation of the generic ST_GEOMETRY standard. The question pertains to Oracle's MDSYS.ST_GEOMETRY datatype. It was implemented differently. Apples to oranges.

Comment: Okay, let's scan the source code and find that `st_pointn` is a member function of type `st_curve` that takes a number as input and returns a `st_point` as output. See [db_fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=b0354d922eeceb61a75c6e1f4b0ef884)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TL;DR]

`SDO_ORDINATES` is a collection attribute of the `MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY` data type.

`ST_POINTN` is a member function of (a super-type of) the `MDSYS.ST_LINESTRING` data type.

---

When you use:

```sql
select sdo_geometry('linestring(1 2, 3 4, 5 6)').sdo_ordinates(1)
from   dual
```

Then it the SQL engine processes the syntax as a call to a member function in the form of `object_type.member_function(argument)` and there is no `SDO_ORDINATES` member function of the `SDO_GEOMETRY` data type and the output is:

> ```
> ORA-00904: "MDSYS"."SDO_GEOMETRY"."SDO_ORDINATES": invalid identifier
> ```

Because there is no `SDO_ORDINATES` member function on the `MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY` object.

---

If instead, you use:

```sql
select (sdo_geometry('linestring(1 2, 3 4, 5 6)').sdo_ordinates)(1)
from   dual
```

Then the SQL engine processes the syntax as `(object_type.collection_attribute)(index)` and the output is:

> ```
> ORA-03001: unimplemented feature
> ```

Because extracting collection elements is not supported in SQL.

---

Finally:

```sql
select treat(
         st_geometry.from_wkt('Linestring(1 2, 3 4, 5 6)',26917)
         as st_linestring
       ).st_pointn(1)
from   dual
```

Returns an `ST_LINESTRING` object type and then you call the `ST_POINTN` member function with the argument `1`. This works because there is a `ST_POINTN` member function declared on `MDSYS.ST_CURVE` which is the super-type of `MDSYS.ST_LINESTRING`.

You can see the object's source using:

```sql
select text
from   all_source
where  type  = 'TYPE'
and    owner = 'MDSYS'
and    name  = 'ST_LINESTRING'
ORDER BY line
```

and then, for it's parent:

```sql
select text
from   all_source
where  type  = 'TYPE'
and    owner = 'MDSYS'
and    name  = 'ST_CURVE'
ORDER BY line
```

Which includes the declaration:

> ```sql
>  MEMBER FUNCTION ST_PointN(aposition INTEGER) RETURN ST_Point DETERMINISTIC,
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=1c56d95cbcf884d1493e3983f9c848d9)*